# Why is my server receiving messages on a port it's not listening to? (UDP)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, network-programming, udp

I have a client and server as separate applications for a unity game. This is my first time writing netcode. My code works, but the way I understand it is that it shouldn't be working.

My client is sending messages on port 7052, and listening to messages from the server on port 7062. On the other side, my server is sending messages on 7062, and listening on 7052. On line 54 and 55 of my client code, we can see the client is listening for messages on 7062 via the sendPort integer. But on the server code at line 60 we are sending the messages on 7052, which is the wrong port. The server should not be receiving these messages as it is listening for 7062, but for some reason the message is being received and outputted.

If I set the port to the correct send port, the server does not receive the message. Could someone explain why my code works like this, and if it is correct/incorrect? I want to continue scaling this for more than 1 client, but I would like to know if this solution is correct before I make this bigger. Thank you for any help you can give.

Server code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
public class Network : MonoBehaviour
{
    TextMeshPro console;        //Reference to console in scene
    Thread receiveThread;       //Thread for listening to messages
    UdpClient client;           //Reference to client
    int recvPort;               //Incoming data port

    string response;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //Assign send and receive ports
        recvPort = 7052;

        //Autoresponse
        response = "Server|Message Received";
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        //Start Listening
        receiveThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReceiveData));
        receiveThread.IsBackground = true;
        receiveThread.Start();

        Debug.Log("Server Started");
    }

    private void ReceiveData()
    {
        //Initialize client by accepting data from any IP on the assigned port
        client = new UdpClient();
        client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        client.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, recvPort));

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                //Check for data from any IP on assigned listening port
                IPEndPoint anyIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, recvPort);
                byte[] data = client.Receive(ref anyIP);

                //Convert byte array message to string and output it
                string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
                Debug.Log(text + " Received on port" + anyIP.Port);

                //Let the client know the data was received
                byte[] resp = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response);
                client.Send(resp, resp.Length, anyIP);
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                //Output socket error
                Debug.Log(err);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

public class Client : MonoBehaviour
{
    Thread receiveThread;           //Thread for listening to messages
    IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint;      //Remote endpoint for server
    UdpClient serverRecv;           //udpclient for server??

    //Connection info
    string IP;
    int recvPort;
    int sendPort;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //Assign connection info to server and inbound/outbound ports
        IP = "127.0.0.1";
        recvPort = 7062;
        sendPort = 7052;
        remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), sendPort);

        //Bind server to socket and start listening
        serverRecv = new UdpClient();
        serverRecv.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        serverRecv.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, recvPort));

        StartListen();
    }

    //Thread listening for messages
    public void StartListen()
    {
        receiveThread = new Thread(
             new ThreadStart(ReceiveData));
        receiveThread.IsBackground = true;
        receiveThread.Start();
    }

    private void ReceiveData()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                //Check for data from server on assigned port
                IPEndPoint serverIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), recvPort);
                byte[] data = serverRecv.Receive(ref serverIP);

                //Convert byte array message to string and output it
                string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
                Debug.Log(text + " Received on port" + serverIP.Port);
                
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                //Output socket error
                Debug.Log(err);
            }
        }
    }

    public void LogIn()
    {
        sendString("Client|Hi! I would like to log in");
    }

    private void sendString(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
            serverRecv.Send(data, data.Length, remoteEndPoint);
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Debug.Log(err);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Receive` is going to block on each side until something is sent. You need two separate `Task.Run` functions which asynchronously send and receive, and some way to synchronize between them.

Answer (score 0):

You never set a port that the server sends messages to the client. The server gets the information but the client never recevies anything  because the server doesn't send info on the port.